# Find a complex algebraic curve.

Tags: complex-numbers, algebraic-curves

> **Definition.** A *complex algebraic curve* is the zero zet of a polynomial $P:\mathbb{C}^2 \to \mathbb{C}$.

If I am given a parametrisation of such a zero set, e.g. $P(t^2, t^3+1)=0, \forall t \in \mathbb{C}$, is there a constructive method to find a polynomial $P(x,y)$ that fulfills this condition for $x=t^2$ and $y=t^3+1$?

Comment: This particular case can be done by hand, just observe that $t^6 = x^3 = (y - 1)^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this can be done using elimination theory. See the reference to Cox, Little, and O'Shea's book I've given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1318832) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1490119).

We can find the desired polynomial by computing a Gröbner basis using [*SageMath*](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/). For the given $x$ and $y$, we find that they satisfy the polynomial $P(x,y) = x^3 - y^2 + 2 y - 1 = x^3 - (y-1)^2$.

Comment: Thank you! Now I know that the approach is not just "trial and error" ... cool! :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a standard way to get an equation for the image of a plane parametrized curve:

$$x = \phi(t) \\
y = \psi(t)$$

From the first equality obtain a polynomial equation for $t$ with coefficients dependent on $x$, and similarly from the second:

$$P(t, x) = 0\\
Q(t, y) = 0$$

Now, impose the condition on the polynomials $P(t)$, $Q(t)$ in $t$ to have a common root $t$. This involves the [resultant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant):

$$\operatorname{Res}(P, Q) = 0$$

The above will be an equation in $x$, $y$.

Let's take a simple example

$$x = \frac{1- t^2}{1+t^2} \\
y = \frac{2 t}{1+t^2}$$

Then

$$P(t, x) = (1+t^2) x - (1-t^2)\\
Q(t,x) = (1+t^2) y - 2 t$$
With WA we [get](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Resultant%5B%20%281%2Bt%5E2%29%20x%20-%20%281-t%5E2%29%2C%20%281%2Bt%5E2%29%20y%20-%202%20t%2C%20t%5D)

$$\operatorname{Res}(P(t), Q(t)) = 4(x^2 + y^2-1)$$